# How to implement an external payment gateway with Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, e-commerce

I need to implement an external payment gateway in Prestashop. I have to send an HTTP request as below:

```
<form method="post" name="payment" action="url">
blah blah....
<input name="ResponseURL" value="{$response}">
</form>
```

The `ResponseURL` is the URL provided by me to retrieve the response from the API. This is where I need to perform validation checking and redirect to the order confirmation page. (similarly to the validation front controller from `ps_checkpayment` module)

I have also added the hookPaymentOption

```
public function hookPaymentOptions($params)
    {
        
        if (!$this->active) {
            return;
        }

        //some code here

        $response = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $this->_path . '/classes/response.php';
 
        $formAction = $this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'validation', array(), true);
 
        $this->smarty->assign([
            //some code here
            'response' => $response
        ]);

        $paymentForm = $this->fetch('module:easypaymentoption/views/templates/hook/payment_options.tpl');
 
        $newOption = new PaymentOption();
        $newOption->setModuleName($this->displayName)
            ->setCallToActionText($this->displayName)
            ->setAction($formAction)
            ->setForm($paymentForm);
 
        $payment_options = array(
            $newOption
        );
 
        return $payment_options;
    }
```

I'm just really clueless as to how to proceed. I've tried to link my `$response` to a front module controller class, but I get an error that says
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ModuleFrontController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\modules\easypaymentoption\classes\response.php:3` .

I have also tried to link to an empty php file, but by doing this I can't get the necessary information to do validation checking and redirect to the order confirmation page that I would otherwise would get by using a class that extends ModuleFrontController.

Any help is appreciated, as I've been stuck here for almost 3 days.

Comment: Need to see your response.php file, but I guess you have defined there a class heritating ModuleFrontController. This way, you can not expect to access that file directly (as seen in your URL). You can do it if you want, but not as a controller, but a custom script, where you can require PrestaShop's config file. But the right way is to do it with a controller, just as I supose you're trying to do. Please take a look to PrestaShop's documentation about developing modules. Maybe the mistake is just the URL.

Comment: Hi @JoséCarlosPHP, thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I can successfully direct the API to the controller now. However, some information from the context is missing in the controller while trying to perform some validation, ($this->context->cart, etc), and when trying to redirect back to the order page after validation failed, the cart will be empty.. do you know what may have caused this?

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, try to use Context::getContext() instead of $this->context. For example, to get the cart: Context::getContext()->cart.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: At this point, I would need to know more about the payment gateway, and see all your code.